# Using AND & OR in Sybase for the WHERE clause?

Tags: database, sybase, where-clause

How can I use AND and OR conditions together in a WHERE clause?

I need to update the table `a` where:
- their primary key/foreign key rows are the same, but
- where 2 other rows between the 2 tables are different.

Example:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.col4 = b.col4,
a.col5 = b.col5
FROM table a, table b
WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND
a.col2 = b.col2 AND
a.col3 = b.col3 AND
a.col4 != b.col4 OR
a.col5 != b.col5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want four conditions to be accomplished, you need to enclose them within parentheses to make clear what has to go together:

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.col4 = b.col4,
a.col5 = b.col5
FROM table a, table b
WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND
a.col2 = b.col2 AND
a.col3 = b.col3 AND
(a.col4 != b.col4 OR a.col5 != b.col5);
^                                    ^
```

This way, you are saying:

```
UPDATE
...
WHERE
condition1 AND condition2 AND condition3 AND condition4
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

being `condition4` the fact that either `a.col4 != b.col4` or `a.col5 != b.col5`.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to put the last condition between brackets :
(a.col4 != b.col4 OR a.col5 != b.col5)